# ASP.NET Custom Membership, Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net

Howdy,
I recently wrote with the help of you guys a login control which logs in against a custom database. I did this using the "validate" method in my Custom Membership control ...

However I want to set a couple Informations in a Session, I am not able to do that in the Membership Generator ... I have to do it on a page which derives of a "page" however this is where my problem starts:

Where and how can I get Data out of the database which is specifically for that user, after I logged in and lost the username/password?

Answer (score 0):

After logging in you may get the user name from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and then you can use it to retrieve the data for that user.

Comment: Since the user could be redirected to any page after the login, I would need to retrieve the user data in every single page ... or is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: You may use User Profile feature that comes with asp.net. http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx